# Anaconda install of Tensorflow missing 'audio_ops' from contrib framework

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to follow along the [Audio Recognition Network](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition) tutorial.

I've created an Anaconda environment with python 3.6 and followed the install instruction accordingly for installing the GPU whl.

I can run the 'hello world' TF example.

When I go to run 'train.py' in the Audio Recognition Network tutorial/example, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 79, in <module>
    import input_data
  File "/home/philglau/speech_commands/input_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops as contrib_audio
ImportError: cannot import name 'audio_ops'
```

The [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/input_data.py) in the tutorial that fails is:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops as contrib_audio
```

I then backed up that chain until I could import some part of it:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.framework as test ==> works
import tensorflow.contrib.framework.python as test --> fail: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.framework' has no attribute 'python'
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong on my install.

Details:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Anaconda env with python 3.6
Followed the 'anaconda' instruction on the TF install page. (GPU version)
```

I also tried using a python 2.7 env for anaconda but got the same results.

Comment: I'm using TF 2.0 in R and have the same issue

Answer (score 7):

It looks like they're releasing the audio_ops modules in version 1.4 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11339#issuecomment-327879009).

Until v1.4 is released, an easy way around this is to install the nightly tensorflow build

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

or with the docker image linked in the issue comment.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:
  The framework is missing the "audio_ops.py" and the example wont work until the file is released. Or you code the wrappers.

More on this:
  If you go to the: tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops local folder you can find other *_ops.py files but not the "audio_ops.py".

If you get it from the Master at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops

You will find the file is almost empty and with import labels wrong: "audio_ops" vs "gen_audio_ops".
With almost empty I mean that: decode_wav, encode_wav, audio_spectrogram , mfcc are not implemented/wrapped.

So, no working example and no fun.
We need to check again when "audio_ops.py" is released.

Here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11339
You can find a Developer saying: "we don't actually want to make them public / supported yet. I'm sorry this decision wasn't better documented"

Comment: If you need to run this. You can use the librosa audio processing. https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/  Also you'll need to correct some regex pattern inside input_data.py